# How can I correctly perform a MySQL query for each result of another query?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to perform a query on a MySQL table based on the results of a query performed right before it.

I'm using NodeJS on Electron. I've tried swapping the "for" loops for "forEach" loops. For some reason, the code is kind of working in that it provides one result, the last one. I expect at least 10 results from the MySQL table but it returns the last one.

```js
con.query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE row=?",[variable], function (err, result, fields) {
    for (var i in result) {
        con.query("SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_TABLE WHERE row=?",[result[i].id], function (err, newresult, fields) {
            var str = '<ul>'

            for (var f in newresult) {
                str += '<li><img src="' + newresult[f].img + '"><span>' + newresult[f].title + '</span></li>';
            }

            str += '</ul>';
            setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById("element").innerHTML = str; }, 100);
        });
    }
});
```

This code returns only one result from the second query when I need it to return all results.

I added a console.log() line to the first query just to check if the first query is getting all of the results, which it is.

Comment: Do you want to display the results of the inner loop or all the results of both loops? Because your outer loop always assigns `str` new.

Comment: I want to display the results from the inner loop but I need to get the id of each row from the outer query.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on that ```str``` new?

Comment: I think you want to take `var str = '<ul>'` out your loop? Wait i post an answer... If its wrong I'll delete it :)

Comment: Oh, I thought it might have to do something with that but I quickly wrote that off. That fixed my problem, thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help... See my answer below :)

Comment: This just seems like a fantastically bad idea. See about JOINs.